# how to create drupal8 ckeditor shortcodes?

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg, shortcode, drupal-8

what would be the best direction toward creating shortcodes usable in drupal 8 editor?

Ckeditor being placed to core, shortcode module nor shortcode_wysiwig module being ported , I am not quite sure where to start from.

Answer (score 1):

you need to implement a custom module using the [ckeditor.api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21ckeditor%21ckeditor.api.php/8)

for further examples see here:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/139075/implementing-ckeditors-plugin-in-drupal-8